# "Search by website" doesn't seem to work consistently

Tags: bug, search, moderator-tools

I ran [this search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=arxiv.org) (as well as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/admin/find-users?q=arXiv.org)), and it did not turn up [this user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic) as it should (his website is set to arXiv). Is something broken here?